# Django extensions error message

Tags: django

Im a django beginner and am using it on a windows machine. Now when i run 'python manage.py runserver', im getting the following message :
**"Error: No module named django_extensions"**
Any way to fix this ?

Thank You

Answer (score 7):

Look inside your settings.py file under the INSTALLED_APPS setting and delete "django_extensions".  Or you can install [django_extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) in this environment.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem. I now only add `django_extensions` in dev mode: `INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + ('django_extensions',)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing a Django application right ? (one you didn't write). It seems you miss some dependencies (at least this one).

You might be able to install it throw easy_install or by executing the setup.py of the following package (django-extension).

You also have to check if you have django_extension in your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings variable, but I'm not quite sure it is needed for django-extension..

Anyway, you might want to install this package : [django-extension](http://github.com/paltman/django-extensions/tree/)